# Comments Notification

Tags: 7, comments

Where is the comment notification when anonymous users send a comment?
I don't find any notification in dashboard, or other pages to approve comments.

Comment: Do you mean you want an email when people add comments?

Comment: I don't know about the topic starter, but I do want an email.

Comment: And I can't believe there is no straightforward and mainstream solution to send an email to the admin for new comments waiting for approval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of unapproved comments is on admin/content/comment.

[image]

Unapproved comments are the comments left from users without the permission of skipping the comment approval, which is given in admin/people/permissions.

[image]

In the site where I took this screenshot, authenticated users are allowed to skip the comment approval, which means that any user with an account is able to write a comment without it gets approved before to be visible to every user.

Comment: oh! tnx alot man.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive an email notification when the anonymous user posts a comment, you can use the [Anonymous Publishing](https://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing) module.

This module can be set up to send e-mail to administrators when anonymous content (inclusing comments) is created.